# ACF - get_field() using 'option' as post_id not working

Tags: custom-field

I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and I have created some options pages with:

```
if (function_exists('acf_add_options_page')) {
    website_settings_init();
}

function website_settings_init() {
    $website_settings = acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title' => 'Website Settings',
        'menu_title' => 'Website Settings',
        'menu-slug' => 'website-settings',
        'post_id' => 'website-settings',
        'redirect' => false
    ));

    $form_settings = acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title' => 'Form Settings',
        'menu_title' => 'Form Settings',
        'menu-slug' => 'form-settings',
        'post_id' => 'form-settings',
        'parent_slug' => $website_settings['menu_slug']
    ));

    $contact_details = acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title' => 'Contact Details',
        'menu_title' => 'Contact Details',
        'menu-slug' => 'contact-details',
        'post_id' => 'contact-details',
        'parent_slug' => $website_settings['menu_slug']
    ));
}
```

I have a field group that is visible if Options Page = Form Settings.

One of these fields is 'thank_you_page' which returns a Page ID.

I read https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/ which describes how you can get values from an options page field using `get_field('field_name', 'option');`

I have tried:

```
get_field('thank_you_page', 'option');
```

This returns `null`. I've tried both `'option'` and `'options'`. However, if I try:

```
get_field('thank_you_page', 'form-settings');
```

I get the saved Page ID. What am I misunderstanding/doing wrong? Is it because it is an options sub page?

I'm using Wordpress 4.9.8 and ACF Pro 5.7.7

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem. It's ***insanely*** poorly documented on [ACF's pages](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/) (as in, not there at all).

The core of your problem is, that you have spaces in your options-page names. And when you access it, using the 'ID', then you have to use the `'page_title'`, but where all spaces are replaced by underscores.

Please note, that it's ***not*** all lowercase. It's written exactly as you've done it, but just replacing the spaces with underscores.

---

### Working example:

In `functions.php`:

```
if( function_exists( 'acf_add_options_page' ) ){

  acf_add_options_page( array(
    'page_title' => 'Some settings',
    'menu_title' => 'Some settings',
    'menu_slug'  => 'some_settings',
    'icon_url'   => 'dashicons-admin-generic',
    'capability' => 'edit_posts',
    'redirect'   => true,
    'position'   => '7.4',
  ) );

  acf_add_options_sub_page( array(
    'page_title'  => 'Acf page with spaces',
    'menu_title'  => 'Acf page with spaces',
    'parent_slug' => 'acf_page_with_spaces',
  ) );

} // endif
```

Where you want to access the fields (like `page.php` or `single.php`).

```
<?php if( have_rows( 'Acf_page_with_spaces', 'option' ) ): ?>
  <?php
  while( have_rows( 'Acf_page_with_spaces', 'option' ) ):
  the_row();
    $foo = get_sub_field( 'foo' );
    $bar = get_sub_field( 'bar' );
    ?>

    <h1><?php echo $foo; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $bar; ?></p>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

There's something about this, that doesn't make any sense, - but that's how it works.

---

### Extra note

This snippet helped me debugging this issue:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r(acf_get_options_pages());
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

It prints all the registered options-pages.

Comment: What does the `post_id` key in the registration args actually do then…?

Answer (score -1):

Note that after struggling with a related issue for a long time, if you remove the `post_id` array parameter from the `acf_add_options_page` that will solve it by using default ACF options keys in the `wp_options` table. (You will need to resave your options on the admin edit options page for this to work, since the database keys will have changed.)

Comment: This isn't really a solution, as it ignores the multiple examples in the original post where they demonstrate that they do in fact want to use something other than the default.

Comment: @ChrisMontgomery I disagree. They are following the documentation, which isn't good, and if they remove that field and use the default ACF value each page will still have its own ID based on the title, which fulfills their need. Just because the ACF documentation is poor in this example doesn't mean this isn't a solution. You aren't required to pass `post_id` here and even in your comment above on Zeth's post you express that you don't understand what the `post_id` registration arg does.